# doInBackgroundTask - AsyncTask - Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am currently using an AsyncTask to fetch the JSON array when pressing a button. After that i have another button called ParseJson which opens a new activity in which a list is shown with the JSONArray.

What i would like, is to have one button instead of 2, but since the getJSON button (first button above) is starting a backgroundtask which needs to be finnished first, before launching the other activity (ParseJSON button), this doesnt work in one button right now.

I heard something about using a loading dialog, but i am quite new to this and have no idea how to solve it.

This is the code i use, but i also need the the value from the Textview in the background task. I will send the value of the textview to a php file (by POST) which fetches the data from the database.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}




public void getJSON(View view) {
    TextView txv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orderID);
    txv.getText().toString; 
    //I need this value in the backgroundtask later 
    new BackgroundTask().execute();

}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    String json_url = "MYJSONURL";
    String JSON_STRING; 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");

            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        json_string = result;
    }
}

public void parseJSON(View view)
{
    if(json_string==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Get JSON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayListView.class);
        intent.putExtra("json_data", json_string);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: add what you have tried

Comment: I have tried to open the other activity in the onPostExecute, but it gave me errors.

Comment: As previously mentioned: post your code. What did you try exactly? Why doesn't onPostExecute not work? What errors did you get? You should be able to chain the AsyncTasks so that they're executed in order. We cannot help you if you don't show us what how you're trying to accomplish this exactly.

Comment: I have posted the code now.

I have tried calling the parseJSON() method in the onPostExecute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of starting the AsyncTask by a button press you code in a way by which it can be started as soon as your main activity is launched. Use onProgressUpdate method of the AsyncTask which will show some progress, once that method is finished your data is loaded. Then you use one button to parse and display the data in the list.

You may refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to know more about AsyncTask methods

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the activity i have a TextView where i enter info of what data the getJSON should fetch, is it still possible?

I am sorry for lefting that out and if it may help i will post the code in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the below code to understand how communication can happen between an activity and AsyncTask. For simplicity I have a count loop running inside AsyncTask which will update the progress on the activity.

Please be warned that this code communicates with the same activity which started the AsyncTask. So, if you would like to perform any such background task, you should be having the AsyncTask attached to your second activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private int mProgressStatus = 0;
    TextView percentage = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        percentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentage);

        new CountProgress().execute();

    }


    class CountProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgress.setProgress(0);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            for (int i=0; i<101;i++ ) {
                if (isCancelled())
                    break;

                publishProgress(i);
                SystemClock.sleep(200);
            }

            return(null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            if (!isCancelled()) {

                mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // updating progress bar value
                mProgress.setProgress(progress[0]);
                // updating progess percentage text
                percentage.setText(progress[0].toString() + "%");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

A full working app code can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/VinodAkkepalli/AndroidStudioProjects/tree/master/BackGroundTask) and you can extend it further for your needs.